# How to store images in mongoDB?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I am using `pymongo` to store user comments in my Django project. I need to save comment images to the database and then show it on a page which is generated by a Django template,
but when I use `request.FILES.get (...)`, `read(...)`, the line does not save in Mongo, because it is not encoded in `utf-8`.

How can I properly save an image into `mongoDB` and then show on an HTML page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving picture to mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915770/saving-picture-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and use this api section: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.2.1/api/bson/binary.html

Wrap it inside of this object and then try and insert/save it.

**Disclaimer**: I have never programmed python so I might be talking jibberish about the wrapping part, either way that page should tell you how to do it.

Comment: No you are correct. You use the Binary object to wrap the string

Comment: Did realise though that I am looking at the old API, appears it's changed: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/api/bson/binary.html#module-bson.binary

Comment: Plus 1 for replying without being a python programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS)? It's a great tool for storing binary data like images in a database.