# How to store Images in MongoDB through pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, opencv, binary, pymongo

```
from PIL import Image
from bson import Binary

img = Image.open('test.jpg')
img = Binary(img)
```

throws an error stating `TypeError : data must be an instance of bytes`

Why does this happen? And how to resolve this to store the img to MongoDB?

Comment: You can check the following answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11916520/7677986

Comment: @MoiSyme Tried. Does not work. Throws the TypeError.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the document doesn't exceed 16MB standard bson is fine, otherwise gridfs should be used. The example below shows how an image can be inserted and read back from a mongodb.

insert_image.py

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from PIL import Image
import io

client = MongoClient()
db = client.testdb
images = db.images

im = Image.open("./image.jpg")

image_bytes = io.BytesIO()
im.save(image_bytes, format='JPEG')

image = {
    'data': image_bytes.getvalue()
}

image_id = images.insert_one(image).inserted_id
```

read_image.py

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.binary import Binary
from PIL import Image
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

client = MongoClient()
db = client.testdb
images = db.images
image = images.find_one()

pil_img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image['data']))
plt.imshow(pil_img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the best answer, it works well and actually deals with pymongo, which was the original question!

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the image into a Byte array. You can do this as follows,

```
from PIL import Image
from bson import Binary

img = Image.open('test.jpg')

imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
img.save(imgByteArr, format='PNG')
imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
```

You can try to save imgByteArr into mongo

**OR**

You can convert image into string and then store it in mongo:

```
import base64

with open("test.jpg", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    //store str in mongo
```

To get back image

```
with open("test2.jpg", "wb") as fimage:
    fimage.write(str.decode('base64'))
```

Comment: Does anyone know which one of these two methods has a better computation efficiency?

Comment: Use @kirk answer, its much better and actually deals with pymongo witch was the original question.